# Is the phrase "an extensive amount of hard work" correct and does is sound natural?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, phrase-choice

What I want to indicate in my writing is that I understand I need to work really hard as a student in the program. I'm using this sentence:

> I am aware that studying in such an intense and demanding program requires **an extensive amount of hard work** and dedication.

My question is, is the phrase "an extensive amount of hard work" correctly used? and if so, does it sound natural? is there a better alternative?

I am trying not to use words like "great" and "huge" too often in my writing that is why I used "extensive".

Answer (score 1):

That doesn’t sound quite right. “Extensive” carries with it connotations of length, depth or detail. It does not simply mean “large”.

Perhaps “a considerable amount of hard work”?